# MVC 5/ReportViewer/ASP.NET client-side AJAX errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, reporting-services

I'm at wits end. I'm trying to load up a ReportViewer with both valid aspx code and ReportViewerForMVC code wind up here. First, the error spread:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < WebResource.axd:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < GetSysWideQuizReport:67
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: ReportViewerForMvc is not defined(anonymous
>   function) @ GetSysWideQuizReport:67  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token <  ScriptResource.axd:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ReportViewerWebForm.aspx:40
>
> Uncaught Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to
>   load.(anonymous function) @ ReportViewerWebForm.aspx:40
>   ScriptResource.axd:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ScriptResource.axd:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ScriptResource.axd:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ReportViewerWebForm.aspx:51
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined(anonymous function) @
>   ReportViewerWebForm.aspx:51  ReportViewerWebForm.aspx:114
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined  ReportViewerWebForm.aspx:114

The View:

```
 @using ReportViewerForMvc;
@using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
@using App.Models;

<style>
    iframe{
        width:900px;
    }
</style>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LocalReportExample";
}


    <h2>Local report example</h2>

@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult GetSysWideQuizReport([Bind(Include = "Topic, Date1, Date2")] QuizReporting quizParams)
            {
                ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
                reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

                reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
                reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
                reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + @"/ReportViews/System Quiz Report.rdlc";
                reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", QuizData(quizParams)));
  ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;

            return View();

 }

        private DataTable QuizData(QuizReporting quizParams)
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("DataSet1");

                using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
                { 

                connection.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SystemQuizReport", connection);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TopicID", quizParams.Topic.TopicID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", "2015/04/13");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", "2015/04/16");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
                }

        }

        static private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return "Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0; Initial Catalog=LocalDb-20140822124213; Integrated Security=True;";
        }
```

An excerpt of web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <!--<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" /> -->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I've done the following to fix it:

- Made sure all Nuget packages/frameworks are up to date
- Examined the console output in Chrome. It looks like the AXD files are trying to render the base home page of my application, and I don't know why.
- Disabled all authorization requirements in FilterConfig and this has not worked.

I'm pulling my hair out so much with this so I hope you can help me out!

Comment: A dumb question, but needed: Have you checked if `ReportPath` is correct?

Comment: Yes, and it is. Perfectly fine question to ask.

Comment: did you fix this issue. I am facing the same thing now after 3 years :(

Comment: I did not - it was easier to just wait for the MS Update to Core.